# Linq to Entity: How to query for multiple Where attributes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

usually when you write a Linq-to-Entity query against a list of attributes, you do this:

```
var attributes = new List<string>();
...
var result = dbContext.TableA.Where(e => attributes.Contains(e.FieldA));
```

But how to do this if you have an object with two or more attributes that need to match one row in the database?

```
class ClassA_DTO
{
  public string AttributeA;
  public string AttributeB;
}
...
var attributes = new List<ClassA_DTO>(); //comes from a JSON web API
...
// e.FieldA needs to match attributes.AttributeA
// AND e.FieldB needs to match attributes.AttributeB
var result = dbContext.TableA.Where(e => ???
```

Comment: does ClassA represent TableA? if so you can do TableA.Where(e => e.AttributeA..)

Comment: @styx ClassA is a DTO

Comment: and how TableA looks in code? are you using EF?

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = dbContext.TableA.Where(e => attributes.Select(a => a.AttributeA).Contains(e.FieldA) && attributes.Select(a => a.AttributeB).Contains(e.FieldB));
```

Using logical gates are possible.